# Compiled Native DLL with CLR, do I have to expose the functions before I can use them?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, c++-cli, clr

I just compiled a native C++ DLL using CLR, and surprisingly I had no errors at all. After referencing the project in my C# project, I noticed that there wasn't anything exposed that I could use. Which I figured would happen. So my question is how can I access these from my c# project? Like I said the project compiles fine with CLR and I can reference it, I just can't access it.

Am I going to have to expose those functions by wrapping them with CLR compliant code? Or is there a way I can easily change some things around and be able to access this DLL in .net?

Comment: It is still very much unmanaged code, even though it got compiled to MSIL.  It simply isn't usable by any other .NET assembly, you *must* write a `public ref class`.  And don't compile native C++ to MSIL, that's just wasteful.  At least look at a C++/CLI tutorial, guessing at this just gets you into endless trouble.

Comment: @HansPassant For one, I don't understand how this is offtopic? It may be vague, although I thought it showed my intentions. Also I don't understand how I was asking for code and why you guys chose that reason? "Questions asking for code must demonstrate......."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is more than one solution for your situation:

1) no object oriented API => you could simply **P/Invoke** (*DllImport*)

2) object-oriented API with few entities => a simple **C++/CLI wrapper**

3) a complex OO API => **SWIG**

4) if you need full interop with the entire world (including techno you don't know) => **COM**